# MCMC algorithm for chemical kinetic parameter estimation

Tags: matlab, bayesian, montecarlo, markov-chains

I'm currently envolved in application of MCMC algorithm to kinetic parameter estimation concerning the example reported below as part of the following reference.

> Beers, Kenneth. Numerical Methods for Chemical Engineering: Applications in MATLAB®. New York, NY: Cambridge University Press, November 2006

MatLab Code at page. 411.

```
% input predictor and response data 
X_pred = [0.1 0.1; 0.2 0.1; 0.1 0.2; 0.2 0.2; 0.05 0.2; 0.2 0.05];
y = [0.0246e-3; 0.0483e-3; 0.0501e-3; 0.1003e-3; 0.0239e-3; 0.0262e-3];

% provide name of routine that returns predicted responses
fun_yhat = 'calc_yhat_kinetic_ex1';
% provide initial guess of parameters
theta_0 = [0.0025 1.0 1.0];
% compute sample variance with initial guess, and use its
% square root as initial guess for sigma
% y_hat = feval(fun_yhat,theta_0,X_pred);
y_hat = feval(fun_yhat,theta_0,X_pred);
RSS_0 = dot(y-y_hat,y-y_hat);
sample_var_0 = RSS_0/(length(y)-length(theta_0));
sigma_0 = sqrt(sample_var_0);
% select the parameters whose 2-D marginal density
% is desired
i_plot_2D = 2; j_plot_2D = 3;
% set the histogram properties
val_lo = [0.8; 0.8]; val_hi = [1.2; 1.2]; N_bins = 50;

%%
% perform the MCMC simulation to compute the
% 2-D marginal posterior density
MCOPTS.N_equil = 50000; % # of equilibration iterations
MCOPTS.N_samples = 25000000; % # of samples
[bin_2Dic, bin_2Djc, bin_2Dp] = ...
    Bayes_MCMC_2Dmarginal_SR(X_pred,y,...
    fun_yhat,i_plot_2D,j_plot_2D,val_lo,val_hi,...
    N_bins,theta_0,sigma_0,MCOPTS);
% generate from the results the 95% HPD region
alpha = 0.05;
HPD_2D = Bayes_2D_HPD_SR(bin_2Dic, bin_2Djc, bin_2Dp, ...
i_plot_2D, j_plot_2D, alpha);
```

Now, the pre-defined functions are the following ones:

fun_yhat = ‘calc yhat kinetic ex1’

```
% calc_yhat_kinetic_ex1.m
function y_hat = calc_yhat_kinetic_ex1(theta, X_pred);

N = size(X_pred,1);  % # of experiments

% extract predictors
conc_A = X_pred(:,1);  % [A] in each experiment
conc_B = X_pred(:,2);  % [B] in each experiment

% extract parameters
k_1 = theta(1);  % rate constant
nu_a = theta(2);  % exponent for [A]
nu_b = theta(3); % exponent for [B]

% make predictions
y_hat = zeros(N,1);
for k=1:N
y_hat(k) = k_1*conc_A(k)^nu_a*conc_B(k)^nu_b;
end
% NOTE, WE COULD SIMPLY USE
% yhat = k1.*(conc_A.^nu_A).*(conc_B.^nu_B);
% TO AVOID SLOW FOR LOOP

return;
```

Bayes_MCMC_2Dmarginal_SR

```
function [bin_ic, bin_jc, bin_p] = ...
    Bayes_MCMC_2Dmarginal_SR( X_pred, y, ...
        fun_yhat, i_plot, j_plot, val_lo, val_hi, ...
       N_bins, theta_0, sigma_0, MCOPTS);

% initialize the output structures
bin_ic = zeros(N_bins,1);  bin_jc = bin_ic;
bin_delta = (val_hi-val_lo)./N_bins;
for k=1:N_bins
    bin_ic(k) = val_lo(1) + (k-0.5)*bin_delta(1);
    bin_jc(k) = val_lo(2) + (k-0.5)*bin_delta(2);
end
bin_p = zeros(N_bins,N_bins);

% set name of routine that returns the
% appropriate predictors for use in
% generating a 2-D marginal density
fun_g = 'calc_g_2Dinterval';
Param.val_lo = val_lo;
Param.val_hi = val_hi;
Param.i_plot = i_plot;
Param.j_plot = j_plot;
Param.N_bins = N_bins;
Param.bin_delta = bin_delta;

% Now, perform the Markov Chain Monte Carlo
% (MCMC) simulation
g_pred = Bayes_MCMC_pred_SR(X_pred, y, ...
    fun_yhat, fun_g, theta_0, sigma_0, MCOPTS, Param);

% From the results of the MCMC simulation, generate
% the 2-D marginal density.
area_bin_inv = 1/bin_delta(1)/bin_delta(2);
for ki = 1:N_bins
    for kj = 1:N_bins
        label = (ki-1)*N_bins + kj;
        bin_p(ki,kj) = g_pred(label)*area_bin_inv;
    end
end

% make contour and surface plots of the 2-D marginal density
% contour plot
figure;
contour(bin_ic,bin_jc,bin_p);
xlabel(['\theta(', int2str(i_plot),')']);
ylabel(['\theta(', int2str(j_plot), ')']);
title('2-D marginal density from MCMC simulation');
% filled contour plot
figure;
contourf(bin_ic,bin_jc,bin_p);  colorbar;
xlabel(['\theta(', int2str(i_plot),')']);
ylabel(['\theta(', int2str(j_plot), ')']);
title('2-D marginal density from MCMC simulation');
% surface plot
figure;
surf(bin_ic,bin_jc,bin_p);
xlabel(['\theta(', int2str(i_plot),')']);
ylabel(['\theta(', int2str(j_plot), ')']);
zlabel(['p(\theta(', int2str(i_plot), ', ', ...
        int2str(j_plot), '| y)']);
title('2-D marginal density from MCMC simulation');

return;
```

Bayes_MCMC_pred_SR

```
function g_pred = Bayes_MCMC_pred_SR(X_pred, y, ...
    fun_yhat, fun_g, theta_0, sigma_0, MCOPTS, Param);

routine_name = 'Bayes_MCMC_pred_SR';
num_arg_in = nargin;

% extract dimension of problem
P = length(theta_0);
N = length(y);

% add default values to MCOPTS as needed
% .N_equil
try
    val = MCOPTS.N_equil;
    if(val < 0)
        error([routine_name, ...
                ': MCOPTS.N_equil < 0']);
    end
catch
    MCOPTS.N_equil = 1000;
end

%  .N_samples
try
    val = MCOPTS.N_samples;
    if(val < 0)
        error([routine_name, ...
                ': MCOPTS.N_samples < 0']);
    end
catch
    MCOPTS.N_samples = 10000;
end

%  .frac_theta
try
    val = MCOPTS.frac_theta;
    if(or((val<=0),(val>=1)))
        error([routine_name, ...
                ': MCOPTS.frac_theta out of (0,1)']);
    end
catch
    MCOPTS.frac_theta = 0.5;
end
        
% .delta_theta
try
    val = MCOPTS.delta_theta;
catch
    MCOPTS.delta_theta = 0.1;
end

% .delta_sigma
try
    val = MCOPTS.delta_sigma;
catch
    MCOPTS.delta_sigma = 0.1*abs(sigma_0);
    if(MCOPTS.delta_sigma < sqrt(eps))
        MCOPTS.delta_sigma = sqrt(eps);
    end
end
    
% .accept_tar
try
    val = MCOPTS.accept_tar;
    if(or((val<=0),(val>=1)))
        error([routine_name, ...
                ': MCOPTS.accept_tar out of (0,1)']);
    end

catch
    MCOPTS.accept_tar = 0.3;
end

% Now, we initialize the counters that keep track of the
% acceptance fractions and the numbers of samples
% taken.
num_theta_try = 0;
num_theta_accept = 0;
num_sigma_try = 0;
num_sigma_accept = 0;
num_samples_taken = 0;

% initialize the running sums of the magnitudes of the
% parameters, and the values avg_mag used in setting
% the step sizes for each parameter.
sum_mag = abs(theta_0);
avg_mag = sum_mag;
k_small = find(avg_mag < sqrt(eps));
avg_mag(k_small) = sqrt(eps);

% with initial theta_0, sigma_0, compute the
% initial vector of predictions, sum of squared
% errors, and posterior probability.
theta = theta_0;
sigma = sigma_0;
y_hat = feval(fun_yhat,theta,X_pred);
residuals = y - y_hat;
SSE = dot(residuals,residuals);
posterior_density = sigma^(-(N+1))* ...
    exp(-SSE/2/sigma^2);

% allocate space to store prediction of g
% and set to initially contain zeros
if(nargin >= 8)
    g_pred = feval(fun_g,theta,sigma,Param);
else
    g_pred = feval(fun_g,theta,sigma);
end
g_pred = zeros(size(g_pred));

% begin Monte Carlo iterations
delta_theta = MCOPTS.delta_theta;
delta_sigma = MCOPTS.delta_sigma;
N_iter_tot = MCOPTS.N_equil + MCOPTS.N_samples;
for iter_MC = 1 : N_iter_tot

    % occasionally, adjust step sizes to fit
    % target acceptance fraction if we have
    % collected enough data since last
    % adjustment. If the acceptance fraction
    % is too low, decrease the step size of
    % the moves.  If too high, increase the
    % step size of the moves.
    if(num_theta_try > 500)
        frac_accept = ...
            num_theta_accept/num_theta_try;
        if(frac_accept < MCOPTS.accept_tar)
            delta_theta = delta_theta * 0.9;
        elseif(frac_accept > MCOPTS.accept_tar)
            delta_theta = delta_theta * 1.1;
        end
        % reset counters
        num_theta_try = 0;
        num_theta_accept = 0;
    end
    % do the same thing for the sigma moves
    if(num_sigma_try > 500);
        frac_accept = ...
            num_sigma_accept/num_sigma_try;
        if(frac_accept < MCOPTS.accept_tar)
            delta_sigma = delta_sigma * 0.9;
        elseif(frac_accept > MCOPTS.accept_tar)
            delta_sigma = delta_sigma * 1.1;
        end
        num_sigma_try = 0;
        num_sigma_accept = 0;
    end        
    
    % decide whether to do theta move or sigma
    % move
    u = rand;  % generate uniform random # on [0,1]
    if(u <= MCOPTS.frac_theta)  % do theta move
        do_theta_move = 1;
        do_sigma_move = 0;
    else
        do_theta_move = 0;
        do_sigma_move = 1;
    end
    if(do_theta_move)   % do theta move
        theta_new = theta + ...
            delta_theta.*avg_mag.* ...
            randn(size(theta));
        num_theta_try = num_theta_try + 1;
        % compute new predictions with this theta, and
        % the new weight according to the posterior
        % density
        y_hat_new = feval(fun_yhat,theta_new,X_pred);
        residuals_new = y - y_hat_new;
        SSE_new = dot(residuals_new,residuals_new);
        posterior_density_new = sigma^(-(N+1))* ...
            exp(-SSE_new/2/sigma^2);
        % compute the acceptance probability
        accept_prob = exp( (SSE - SSE_new) / (2*sigma^2) );
        if(accept_prob > 1)
            accept_prob = 1;
        end
        % decide whether to accept the move or not
        u = rand;
        if(u <= accept_prob)  % accept the move
            theta = theta_new;
            y_hat = y_hat_new;
            residuals = residuals_new;
            SSE = SSE_new;
            posterior_density = posterior_density_new;
            num_theta_accept = num_theta_accept + 1;
        end
    end
    if(do_sigma_move) % do sigma move
        sigma_new = sigma + delta_sigma*randn;
        num_sigma_try = num_sigma_try + 1;
        % compute the acceptance probability
        if(sigma_new <= 0)
            accept_prob = 0;
        else
            % compute new posterior density (but note that
            % the value of SSE does not change)
            posterior_density_new = -sigma_new^(-(N+1))* ...
                exp(-SSE/2/sigma_new^2);
            accept_prob = (sigma_new/sigma)^(-(N+1)) * ...
                exp(SSE/2*(-1/(sigma_new^2) + 1/(sigma^2)));
            if(accept_prob > 1)
                accept_prob = 1;
            end
        end
        % decide whether to accept the move
        u = rand;
        if(u <= accept_prob)
            sigma = sigma_new;
            posterior_density = posterior_density_new;
            num_sigma_accept = num_sigma_accept + 1;
        end
    end
    
    % if we are in the sampling stage, then measure the function
    % g(theta,sigma) and add to running sum.
    if(iter_MC > MCOPTS.N_equil)
        if(nargin >= 8)
            g_meas = feval(fun_g,theta,sigma,Param);
        else
            g_meas = feval(fun_g,theta,sigma);
        end
        g_pred = g_pred + g_meas;
        num_samples_taken = num_samples_taken + 1;
    end
    
    % increment the values of sum_mag and avg_mag
    sum_mag = sum_mag + abs(theta);
    avg_mag = sum_mag/(iter_MC+1);
    k_small = find(avg_mag < sqrt(eps));
    avg_mag(k_small) = sqrt(eps);
    
end

% get prediction from sum of measured predictions
g_pred = g_pred/num_samples_taken;


return;
```

I am not able to write the missing function fun_g = 'calc_g_2Dinterval'; enclosed in the Bayes_MCMC_2Dmarginal_SR function. I have tried to write it but I think that some mistake are present because the main code dose not work/run.

```
function g = calc_g_2Dinterval(theta,sigma,Param);

if((theta(Param.j) >= Param.val_lo(2)) & ...
        (theta(Param.j) <= Param.val_hi(2)))
    g(2) = 1;
else
    g(2) = 0;
end

if((theta(Param.i) >= Param.val_lo(1)) & ...
        (theta(Param.i) <= Param.val_hi(1)))
    g(1) = 1;
else
    g(1) = 0;
end

return;
```

Do you have any suggestions or solution? Thanks.

The error messages that MatLab prints, are the following one:

```
Reference to non-existent field 'j'.

Error in calc_g_2Dinterval (line 3)
if((theta(Param.j) >= Param.val_lo(2)) & ...

Error in Bayes_MCMC_pred_SR (line 175)
    g_pred = feval(fun_g,theta,sigma,Param);

Error in Bayes_MCMC_2Dmarginal_SR (line 72)
g_pred = Bayes_MCMC_pred_SR(X_pred, y, ...

Error in example_411 (line 29)
    Bayes_MCMC_2Dmarginal_SR(X_pred,y,...
```

---

I posted this question on Cross Validated since topic related to statistics, but it was pointed out to me that I had posted on the wrong section. I hope this section (related to programming) is the correct one and I am not off-topic.

I link here the original question:
[The original question posted on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629346/mcmc-algorithm-for-chemical-kinetic-parameter-estimation)

Comment: I’ve copied your original question into here, so we don’t need to click on links to see the actual question.

Comment: So what you’re saying is that you copied code from a book, but for some reason one function was missing? And you’re guessing as to what that function is supposed to look like?

Comment: Note that where `Param` is defined, it gets a field `j_plot`, but not a field `j`. This is why you get an error when trying to access the field `j`, it doesn’t exist, as the error message helpfully explains.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have checked and fixed it

Comment: I've been working on my code since my previous comment - the new error is `Index exceeds matrix dimensions` I know the meaning of Index exceeds matrix but I am not able to recognize it in `bin_p(ki,kj) = g_pred(label)*area_bin_inv;` (this part is inside the Bayes_MCMC_2Dmarginal_SR function code)